# Dataflow jobs fail with: Shuffle close failed: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Dataflow jobs fail with the following error:

```
INFO:root:2018-10-15T18:55:37.417Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Workflow failed. 
Causes: S17:fold2/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+write instances fold2/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+write instances fold2/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write failed., 
A work item was attempted 4 times without success. 
Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on: 
  yuri-nine-gag-recommender-10151140-3kmq-harness-mdgd,
  yuri-nine-gag-recommender-10151140-3kmq-harness-mdgd,
  yuri-nine-gag-recommender-10151140-3kmq-harness-41dd,
  yuri-nine-gag-recommender-10151140-3kmq-harness-mdgd
```

Digging into the logs shows only one error:

```
An exception was raised when trying to execute the workitem 6479210647275353150 : 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 642, in do_work work_executor.execute() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 158, in execute op.finish() 
File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 144, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.ShuffleWriteOperation.finish def finish(self): 
File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 145, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.ShuffleWriteOperation.finish with self.scoped_finish_state: 
File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 147, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.ShuffleWriteOperation.finish self.writer.__exit__(None, None, None) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 599, in __exit__ self.writer.Close() 
File "third_party/windmill/shuffle/python/shuffle_client.pyx", line 202, in shuffle_client.PyShuffleWriter.Close IOError: Shuffle close failed: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide a job id?  I can look into this.

Comment: Thank you for offering help! I already figured out the problem, but unfortunately dataflow logs were not useful this time :)

Comment: @CharlesChen Hi Charles, the problem returned. Can you take a look at one of my jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem by removing various pieces for code, printing tons of logs and running the job again. It turned out that I had a regular expression that blew up for one particular entry. Unfortunately, Dataflow logs were not helpful at all.

Comment: Thank you--what was the root cause, and what sorts of logs would have been most helpful here?  Was this a out-of-memory issue?

Comment: @CharlesChen There was no indication why workers failed, but probably it was out-of-memory issue. I can provide job ids, maybe you could dig in and see the underlying cause? From there maybe you could see what logs would be the most helpful?